# Why do I get, "Firebase: Error getting verification code from microsoft.com response: ..." when implementing Microsoft SSO Provider?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, microsoft-oauth

I'm using StyledFirebaseAuth to add Google, Microsoft, and Email/Password Authentication Buttons to my login experience for my users. Google and Email seem to work ok, but Microsoft keeps throwing me errors.

Here is my configuration:
[Configuration for the ui with tenant field commented out (will explain later)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byffd.png)

[Instance of StyledFirebaseAuth where I base it the uiconfig and my firebase authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13rb5.png)

[Here is me setting up "authentication" that is used in StyledFirebaseAuth that is imported into the other file above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPyeO.png)

This is the full error I get when I keep the "tenant" in the "custom parameters" field of the ui config is commented out:
"Firebase: Error getting verification code from microsoft.com response: error=invalid_request&error_description=Proof%20Key%20for%20Code%20Exchange%20is%20required%20for%20cross-origin%20authorization%20code%20redemption.&state=AMbdmDkS0XK8xpLjDoFV8wtniUXM8DvKvYDLn3SdbTMonrOel10NHMvyH32gQxnI7IiCvVE0b7eaSdauhdKruqrEUbPXF9PXXQuHaqh4tfZJX8IDw-kdOOPoJVAvgoUcT3xTDc8kSgvrTY1FakLAi_xxOKMteo5WsfIRlPztYNxxhpD10CSeRnVen30N-hJBz8nZ7Zv1Nwo3bcsTc7Azy4iGUPdBQkm8CGZuGHs-ll9l6Gbqg3ZTcJUZwAxeeNaoV7LUEJ1A_N2uSbJ0jelTr2inIn3gzf9ZX8Zs665vlCpv6sYlwWH71YWZy6cnP9pvu-xgSMsIJKSj3thVQ7h6MsEbjPK-Q7bM4E4drQhu9Fz8nFE (auth/invalid-credential)."

When I uncomment out the tenant field, I get this error:
User account '{{email}}' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application '{{client id}}'{{app display name}} in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Here is my dashboard on the Azure Portal if that is of any help:
[Azure Portal Dashboard Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqYdv.png)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've seen this question asked before on here, but the solution didn't work for me.

Open to any suggestions you guys have. Let me know if you need anymore information!!!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. You need to check if you your websites SSL certificate is valid. If not make sure that the SSL certificate is installed correctly.

This sorted out the issue.